# Problem running React Native code on gennymotion emulator

Tags: android, react-native

"Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048) could not read ok from ADB Server * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemo"

I'm getting this error when i try to run my React Native code on gennymotion emulator. As i'm new to react native so i don't know much how to solve this problem.
I write my code on VScode and run on external device and it works perfectly but as i need to debug by code so i have to run it on simulator(I guess).I've downloaded android studio but I dont know what to do with it.It would be great if I get a detailed answer.